# Printing documents without opening it

Tags: c#, printing

I have to print multiple documents from grid.

I have used **ProcessInfo** class to accomplish this task and it is working fine but the problem is that the document is opened and closed every time for each document. That is what I don't want.

Please don't suggest `office automation` because I have other documents format also like `.pdf, .rtf, .txt` etc.

Code:

```
Process P = new Process();
P.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;//e.g. "c:/test.docx"
P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
P.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
P.Start();
```

Comment: Please show an example of your code. It's much easier for us to correct your code than to write the application for you.

Comment: Also please comment on how you want document to be printed without beeing opened first (assuming your are talking about file being accessed)...

Comment: suppose document is saved in any directory. Now i have to print this document without opening it and also application should not open when we give print command. it should directly go to printer.

Comment: How does the printer know how to print it without the intervention of a program that knows how to render it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to use `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(yourDocumentFilename);
info.Verb = "Print";
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
```

You can find more information about it on [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle).